# How to get the current temperature and tint for an AVCaptureDevice?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I figured out how to adjust the temp and tint of an existing session with `deviceWhiteBalanceGainsForTemperatureAndTintValues` which takes a parameter of `AVCaptureWhiteBalanceTemperatureAndTintValues`. But I'm struggling to figure out a way to read the current of new value.

Any one know of a way to do this? I would like to set `UISliders` with the values of the Temp and Tint.

Comment: I have never used this stuff, but according to the documentation there is a `deviceWhiteBalanceGains` property and a `temperatureAndTintValuesForDeviceWhiteBalanceGains()` method.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly it. I totally overlooked it from the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Martin answered it in the comments.

```
let tempAndTintValues = activeCameraDevice.temperatureAndTintValuesForDeviceWhiteBalanceGains(activeCameraDevice.deviceWhiteBalanceGains)
```